# How to handle token refresh on 401 error occurrence in Nextjs 13 app directory server component?

Tags: next.js

What is the best way to handle token refresh on 401 error occurrence in server component?
Currently our main layout is client component using 'use client' to handle 401 error cases dynamically. If a 401 error occurs we call an API with the refresh token to retrieve refreshed access token. Since it uses hooks like useEffect, we declared as a client component. Then a curiosity occurred to me, 'How should I handle 401 cases that is happening in a server component?' 'Do I have to use client component without choice, since I have to react on to 401 cases?' I wanted to search for best practices but i couldn't

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also you're missing a real [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The information you give is not enough to say answer but you can do this:

Check user auth in API section and if the token is expired or not has correct sign, delete / refresh it in API section and redirect it to a page that you want.

Editing and validating the token must be in backend for security reasons.